# Generic in superclass that can handle child class type

Tags: java, android, generics, inheritance, sugarorm

I'm trying to move duplicated code into a parent class, but such code uses 'details' from the specific class.

#### Duplicated code exampe

Client.java

```
class Client extends SugarRecord {
    private String uuid; // name, etc
    public static Client findByUuid(String uuid){ // null check
        List<Client> clients = find(Client.class, "uuid = ?", uuid);
        return clients.get(0); // simplified, but checks for empty list and ret. null
    }
}
```

Foo.java

```
class Foo extends SugarRecord {
    private String uuid; // bar, etc
    public static Foo findByUuid(String uuid){ // null check
        List<Foo> foos = find(Foo.class, "uuid = ?", uuid);
        return foos.get(0); // simplified, but checks for empty list and ret. null
    }
}
```

*Note: `SugarRecord` comes from SugarORM.*

As you can see, this is repetitive and only changes the *Something*.class. And this could be made to other things too, such as `findAll()`.

#### Intended way

My intention was to use it like so:

```
Client client = Client.findByUuid("abc");
```

#### Problem

When I try to move code into the parent class, I don't know how to both resolve the generic type and to make it callable in the desired way. For example, I could declare a method in the parent class:

public class MyBaseClass extends SugarRecord{
    public static  T findByUuid(Class c, String uuid){
        List result = find(c, "uuid = ?", uuid);
        return result.get(0);
    }
}

calling it like so:

```
Client cli = Client.findByUuid(Client.class, "something");
```

But I'd like to omit the *Something*.class.

---

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Implement `findByUuid(Class<T> c, String uuid)` in the base class.

```
class SugarRecord {
    protected static <T> T findByUuid(Class<T> c, String uuid) {
        List<T> result = find(c, "uuid = ?", uuid);
        return result.get(0);
    }
}
```

Call it from sub-class methods:

```
class Client extends SugarRecord {
    public static Client findByUuid(String uuid) {
        return findByUuid(Client.class, uuid);
    }
}
```

Use it like you wanted:

```
Client client = Client.findByUuid("abc");
```

Comment: This requires a `findByUuid` in each one of the children. As of now, I have a DatabaseUtil class that has the same generic method as yours, and I call it from each "regular" class the same way as your sub-class example. It's fine, but I was looking for alternatives for it xD. Anyways, thanks for your input.

Comment: Btw, SugarRecord is a superclass of the BaseClass (3 levels total). I edited your answer so others working with it understand. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @FirstOne I do mind, because the change made the answer not fit the question. You know, the question where *you* wrote `class Client extends SugarRecord`

Comment: `SugarRecord` is a class from `SugarORM`, not mine. So it's not possible to exist `SugarRecord` with `findByUuid` method. The idea is to create a middle-class to have duplicate code. So, `Cliente extends MyBaseClass`, and `MyBaseClass extends SugarRecord`. `SugarRecord` is the one with method `find`. It fits perfectly in the question.

Comment: @FirstOne That is minutia of your setup, what wasn't covered in question, and doesn't affect concept of answer. The `findByUuid(Class<T> c, String uuid)` doesn't even have to be in base class, it can be anywhere, e.g. in a helper/utility class. Remember, StackOverflow answers are for general use, and doesn't have to fit your specific question 100%, although my answer did fit the question 100% when I wrote it.

Comment: I already have that setup (utility), but I was looking for an alternative which would allow me to skip the "base-class" implementation of `findByUuid`, since it's the same for all of them, except for the `Something.class` part. Anyways, Thanks for your input.